# Sourcing one sql inside another sql file gives Error 2 : Failed to open file

Tags: mysql

I have two sql files. From one file, I am trying to source the other file and execute the commands in the other file.

Eg, Say I have two files `a.sql and b.sql` in the same directory.

```
a.sql
------

use dbName;
source b.sql
# bunch of sql statements

b.sql
------

use dbName;
# bunch of sql statments
```

Now, when I am trying to exexute the command as below,

```
mysql -u root -p dbName < /path/to/a.sql
Enter password: 
ERROR at line 2: Failed to open file '/b.sql', error: 2
```

I have browsed through similar questions here at SO, but most of them suggest to use absolute path, however I want to use the relative path of b.sql in a.sql, as it will be migrated to prod environment and so giving absolute path won't make any sense.

Please let me know how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

From terminal, go to your folder :

```
cd /path/to/
```

Then, log into MYSQL terminal

```
mysql -uroot -p dbName
Enter password:
```

Then, source these files

```
source a.sql
```

Note that the first two commands are from terminal, and the last one is from MYSQL terminal.